# CSS Positioning - Multiple Background Position Properties?

Tags: css

Is there a way to set multiple background-position properties for a single element?  Depending on the state of a link (pressed/hover/default), I need to both change the X and Y values of the image being displayed.

I'd like to have the Y values static in my CSS files, while the X position needs to change per each element in my nav bar (which the links go in).

Is there a way to do this?  Looking online, I haven't found a way to set just the top or just the left parameter for background-position.

Comment: I can solve this myself with jQuery.  If there is a simpler way of doing it than using jQuery, please do let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Apparently](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/background-position),

> [background-position] accepts one or two length values, percentages, or
>   keywords.
>
> If only one value is specified for background-position, the second
>   value is assumed to be center. Where two values are used, and at least
>   one is not a keyword, the first value represents the horizontal
>   position, and the second represents the vertical position.

You will most likely have to rely on JavaScript to preserve those Y values.

Comment: My problem is that setting background-position again completely rewrites the older one.  I need to be able to set this twice (because the X position will be changing dynamically).  I can do this with jQuery I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this CSS to change the background image position for a element depending on its state (regular, hover, or active)... assuming you are using a sprite for your background:

```
#NavElement {
   background-image:url(../img/button.png);
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
   background-position:top center;
}

#NavElement:hover {
   background-position: center; /* center is assumed as the second value */
}

#NavElement:active {
   background-position:bottom center;
}
```

Also, you can specify the position in px rather than bottom, top, or center.

Comment: Only problem with that I have to set a new X position from within the code.  It'll be specific to the particular link selected.  It would overwrite the current background-position setting (thus, my problem).

Comment: you could use js to set the background position: object.style.backgroundPosition="Xpx, Ypx" ... however I don't think that I fully understand your question, could you post your code?

Comment: I did use jQuery to get what I want.  I needed to access different X/Y coordinates at different times and dynamically.  Setting a single CSS class wouldn't help, so I have to use jQuery. 

What would have helped is `background-position-x` or `background-position-y` - it's just those two settings are not standard.  I need to be able to alter one coordinate WITHOUT altering the other, but when you try to use `background-position` then it will ignore any other previous settings.